# Could I restart netbeans without restarting netbeans managed tomcat ?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

When I restart netbeans the tomcat instance managed by it also stops, therefore I need to restart it when netbeans is restarted, Is there any way to simply prevent tomcat from stopping at certain times, when netbeans is restarted ?

Comment: Deploy a non-netbeans tomcat separately. Other than that, don't really think it's plausible. Unless your definition of `restarting netbeans` does not involve complete application exit.

Comment: yes that's option but I like to develop with netbeans managed tomcat to keep things easy, as I am using tools like Jrebel etc.. to hot delpy changes, doing that on non managed tomcat (I think) would be a bit messy..

Comment: To keep your own workstation tidy from excess tomcat processes, you could alternatively deploy your tomcat on a remote cloud service (for example: Openshift (They also offer free plans)), and have it running all the time and not worry even about computer restarts etc. Not sure how difficult it would be to configure it with tools like JRebel though, so there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Just Start your tomcat directly from your tomcat folder , what do you mean by restart netbean? only close netbean or close all open file in netbeans